# Azure Active Directory authenticaiton using Google Cloud Run

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, google-cloud-run

I develope an application by .NET Core 3.1 and I deploying it in Google Cloud Run with Azure Active Directory authentication. My URL is `https://xxxxx-yyyyyy-ue.a.run.app/` and I have been configured it in URL reply in Authentication tab with `https://xxxxx-yyyyyy-ue.a.run.app` and `https://xxxxx-yyyyyy-ue.a.run.app/signin-oidc` . But when I trying access the error is displayed:

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the
>   reply URLs configured for the application: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.

This same app, when deployed in Azure App Web ok. I guess that this error is because the URL that Cloud Run send to Azure Active Directory is different than `https://xxxxx-yyyyyy-ue.a.run.app`.

My URL reply at Azure AD is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBnhF.png)

My appsettings.json is like this:

`... "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Domain": "domain.com.br",
    "TenantId": "9999999999999999",
    "ClientId": "8888888888888888",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  } ...`

and my ConfigureServices at Startup.cs is like this:

`services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddAzureAD(options => config.Bind("AzureAd", options));`

I still think the problem may be with the URI that Cloud Run sends to Azure AD. It must be an address other than https://xxxxx-yyyyyy-ue.a.run.app.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share us more details or screenshots explaining how you have set up reply url in  your app in  azure and cloud run.

Comment: HI @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity I shared more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the mismatch between the redirect URL you requested and the redirect URL you configured in the Azure portal. The redirect URL needs to be registered in the Azure portal to create a connection to the application.

Go to `"Azure portal"` >`"Azure Active Directory"`> `"Application Registration"`> `"Your Application"`> `"Authentication"` and configure the URL that users should be directed to after logging in. The redirect URL in the portal needs to exactly match the configuration in the application code.

The redirect_uri in your request is `https://xxxxx-yyyyyy-ue.a.run.app`, so please check the redirect url in Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: Hi Carl Zhao, locally with http://localhost:5000 it's ok for me. When a deploy it to public URL 
is that the issue happens. Off course that I change my url reply too. Thanks.